# Hot Deploy for JBoss on Eclipse 3.4: Ganymede

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jakarta-ee, ganymede

I am using Ganymede (Eclipse 3.4) to do some Java EE based web development targeting a JBoss 4.2 application server.

I have always liked Eclipse very much for a Java editor. The thing is, for Java EE is not as useful as one might think. It's buggy, deployment and debugging is very slow, and you have to re-deploy your Java EE application every time you make a little change. That makes development unbearable.

My question is: Is there a plugin that will make my life easier by adding HOT DEPLOY to Ganymede when developing JBoss Applications?

Comment: I suggest putting "JBoss" into the title too, since there are many more application servers for which hot deploy would be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use JBoss tools:

http://www.jboss.org/tools

I've used this when developing on JBoss using Eclipse 3.4, it works well although there are still some bugs in the plugin.  Overall though it's better.

Update site for 3.4.2 is:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/

**EDIT**: Also, if you're running on Redhat you can download JBoss Developer Studio which is "guaranteed" to provide a development environment that is stable and deployable.  I've not used it, but interested to see whether it lives up to those claims:

http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/

Comment: JBoss Developer Studio 2.0 is pretty good. I've been using Eclipse and JBoss Tools for ages and only recently started with the whole studio. Impressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this out of the box with remote debugging.  Connect the Eclipse debugger to JBoss and when you make a code change it will be hot-patched where possible.

There's a tutorial on doing so [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/08/31/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html)