# Hot deployment location in Wildfly 8 AS

Tags: java, maven, wildfly-8, hotdeploy

In JBoss 6 AS, the hot deployment location is `${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy` where I can unpack WAR or EAR and change content of any configuration file and it works without restart.

Similarly, in Wildfly 8 AS, can anyone help me to know about the hot deployment location. I tried unpacking WAR in `${WILDFLY_HOME}/standalone/deployments` folder but it is not picking up the unpacked WAR folder. It considers file only with .war extension. Can anyone help me on the same. Many thanks.

Also, if there is a good guide on usage of `wildfly-maven-plufgin`, please share m
Can anyone help me on the same. Many thanks.

Comment: You followed all the steps in the documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Application+deployment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full documentation is found here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment%20Scanner%20configuration.html

What you need to do to enable automatic deployment of exploded (unpacked) archives is to set the `auto-deploy-exploded` to `true` in your *standalone.xml* configuration file:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
    <deployment-scanner 
        scan-interval="5000"
        relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
        path="deployments"
        auto-deploy-exploded="true" />
</subsystem>
```

This would scan the deployments directory every 5 seconds for exploded archives.

As stated in the documentation, without the `auto-deploy-exploded` property, you would need to manually create a *.dodeploy* file:

> Controls whether exploded deployment content should be automatically deployed by the scanner without requiring the user to add a .dodeploy marker file. Setting this to 'true' is not recommended for anything but basic development scenarios, as there is no way to ensure that deployment will not occur in the middle of changes to the content.

Comment: Hi, but how will it know which class files are changed in the project?