# How do I make an Auto Deployment in Wildfly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly

I know Wildfly can't do hot deployment, but its able to do (at least) auto deployment.

I'm using `Eclipse`, and `Maven`.

I'd like that when I `Run` (or `Debug`) the project, it will compile the whole, copy the target `.war` to `standalone\deployments`'s wildfly folder, and than Wildfly must be able to catch the change without restart the server, of course. So, once compiled, I can immediatly use the changes in the project.

How can I do it? I can't find any tutorial or tips online. Fancy help?

Comment: Without doing a restart ? There are situation where you can't prevent that. Apart from that what does Wildfly not support hot deployment (Question: What do you understand by hot deployment?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771904/hot-deployment-location-in-wildfly-8-as ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969279/hot-deploy-on-jboss-how-do-i-make-jboss-see-the-change/38403724#38403724

Comment: Ok than you can only go via JBoss tools in Eclipse and do it from there...and you have to live with those things or you buy JRebel...

Comment: @khmarbaise: can you show me how to do it? Thats the question...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the exploded content and jboss-cli or whatever client you want to overwrite your class file. But you will need to redeploy your deployment since hot-deploy through jpda only works if the code signature doesn't change. JBoss Tools should do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, eclipse debug mode can make hot deploy to wildfly. But sometimes it would not work.

And Intellij debug mode can make hot deploy to wildfly, it works really well. But for add new class, new annotations, new method, new attributes still needs restart. Changing logic within method is fine.